# How to report failed testcase in jira using automation

Tags: selenium, jira

I am automating a website using selenium webdriver with java, I want to write the result "Pass" or "Fail" in excel sheet. How can i automate  the reporting of a failed test case in JIRA by taking the status from excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already writing to an excel file, I understand that you are able to access the contents of the Excel Sheet. If this is not completed yet, you might want to consider using http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html for this purpose. Once you have the status of the test cases, you can use the JIRA API to create bugs https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Home. A more specific example of how to do this is mentioned here (https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Create+Issue). 
However, since a bug (defect) usually requires more information than a simple PASS / FAIL, I would suggest that you might want to collect more information like the stack trace etc and save it in the excel file (or an XML file) when the test fails. 
Which test runner are you using? If it is JUnit / TestNG, I believe a XML file is created by default for a test run, which might have some of this information.

Comment: Ys ,the pass or fail status is in excel sheet. and can i use the step id ,description etc from the excel sheet for creating the bug.? and i dont have idea to use json .how can i implement if?

Comment: http://www.j-tricks.com/1/post/2012/05/java-rest-client-for-jira-using-jersey.html There is a section for creating an issue over here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Apache POI' to read cells from Excel sheet and 'Jira Client' to update status in Jira. 
'Jira Client' is a JIRA REST based client library for Java. You can read more about this here: https://github.com/rcarz/jira-client/blob/master/README.md